# Dynamic UITableView height in embedded view

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, autolayout, uistoryboard

I have a table view as part of a larger controller. This table view can have various number of rows and rows are expandable (e.g. unselected state is `50pt`, selected -> `120pt`).

To animate sell expanding/collapsing I use those methods:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
    view.setNeedsLayout()
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
    view.setNeedsLayout()
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

But I need to update container view height in parent view controller together with the table view. 
I've tried to achieve that by adding observer to the `contentSize` of the tableView and assigning its height to the `containerView` height constraint. Its kinda work but animation of the `containerView` height happens after cell increase/decrease animation already happened.

Is there a way to achieve dynamic height table view in embedded view controller?

PS. I don't want to use table view footer/header to put surrounding views there as surrounding view structure is more complex and table view is just part of it.

[image]